# Html to PDF with webkit transform

Tags: html, pdf

When producing PDF from Html the webkit transform does not work. I need to rotate a div at 45 angle and after using webkit transform it looks ok on the screen but with winnovatives Html to PDF convertor the out put was flat not rotated. Any solutions?

Answer (score 6):

Try: "[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)" it just work great. It uses **webkit** engine and it is very easy to use:

```
wkhtmltopdf stackoverflow.com/questions/3849441/ output.pdf
```

Try it! for Linux and Windows as well. Easy to install. If you use ubuntu, type:

```
aptitude install wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: it does work great, but it's GPL which means I can't use it in a project I'm working on.  Any other good ones?

Comment: You can use it. Just don't link against the binary. Call it as an external binary and provide sources for it in case someone demands it.

Answer (score 1):

Winnovative HTML to PDF rendering engine is compatible with WebKit (Google Chrome) and you have to use '-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);' style in CSS to rotate an element.

Comment: if you provide  me  any valuable link or proof will be very helpful for me